# Como crear ordenes de compra con PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, api, transbank

Estimados tengo la siguiente problematica. Estoy usando un sistema de pagos llamado Transbank el cual estoy integrando en PHP. Dicho sistema me solicita los siguientes parametros
•Precio
•Orden de Compra
•IdSesion
•UrlInicial
•UrlFinal
Con los parametros ingresados se genera un token el cual lleva la url que redirige al portal de pagos con los datos ingresados mas arriba.
Tengo una base de Datos donde quiero almacenar las Ordenes de Compra que se vallan generando cuando alguien paga algun producto, con los campos
•ordencompra
•cantidad
•precio
•total

El problema viene cuando en el portal de pago antes de confirmar el pago, esta la opcion de volver atras y no llevar acabo la compra. Entonces mi duda es como genero la orden de compra de forma correlativa, considerando que esta no se puede llevar cabo (ya sea porque el cliente se arrepintio o se cerro el navegador) y la orden quede liberada por decirlo de alguna forma.

Comment: Prueba usar tareas programadas (crontab) que comprueben el estado de la operación cada X minutos. Es muy importante que utilices un campo de control en la base de datos que controle el estado de la operación (por ejemplo: pendiente, finalizada, cancelada). Por favor facilítanos más información.

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo del uso de la versión REST o SOAP de Transbank los métodos cambian, pero la idea es la misma. En los ejemplos usaré la configuración del ambiente de integración

## Paso 1: Crear la Transaccion

Voy a hacer un par de funciones para traerme una transacción lista para que tú mandes al cliente a trasbank:

[En REST inicias una transacción usando Transaction::create](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay#crear-una-transaccion-webpay-plus):

```js
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus\Transaction;
use Transbank\Webpay\Options;

function createRestTransaction($buyOrder, $amount) {
   $config = Options::defaultConfig();

   return Transaction::create(
              $buyOrder, 
              session_id(),
              $amount,
              TU_URL_FINAL,
              $config
            );
 }
```

[En SOAP se usaba initTransaction](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay-soap?l=php#crear-una-transaccion-webpay-plus-normal):

```js
use Transbank\Webpay\Webpay;
use Transbank\Webpay\Configuration;

function createSoapTransaction($buyOrder, $amount) {

  $config = Configuration::forTestingWebpayPlusNormal();

  $transaction = (new Webpay($config))->getNormalTransaction();
    
  return $transaction->initTransaction(
                  $amount, 
                  $buyOrder, 
                  session_id(), 
                 TU_URL_DE_TRANSICION, // esto nunca supe para qué
                 TU_URL_FINAL
                );
 }
```

Fíjate que en ambas API lo relevante son  `$buyOrder`y `$amount`. El resto se saca de constantes (tus url) o son valores efímeros (la sesión)

Tú quieres hacer una tabla de pedidos que tiene esos campos

> quiero almacenar las Ordenes de Compra ..., con los campos •ordencompra •cantidad •precio •total

Genial, siempre que  ordencompra sea único y ojalá hasta llave primaria. En ese caso un ejemplo muy burdo usando PDO y sin procuparme de capturar excepciones (con suerte me di el trabajo de usar sentencias preparadas!) sería

```
 $ordencompra=time();  // esto no lo uses en producción!
 $precio = 100; //tú sabrás cuanto vale
 $cantidad = 2; // y cuantas unidades son
 $total = $precio * $cantidad;
```

Con esos datos podrías tanto generar una transacción como guardar en tu tabla.

#### Pero esa tabla no estaría completa sin el campo token

Cuando creas esa transacción te dará un token:

```
// en rest
$token = createRestTransaction($ordencompra,$total)->getToken();

// o en SOAP
$token = createSoapTransaction($ordencompra,$total)->token;
```

Y tú como ya debes saber con ese token haces un formulario donde el cliente termina en la pasarela de pago.

Justo antes de eso tú creas el registro porque, comprensiblemente, quieres almacenar incluso los casos donde el proceso no se completa.

(de nuevo, lo encapsularé en una función). El parámetro $conn es la conexión a tu BBDD en este ejemplo burdo

```js
 function storeOrdenCompra($conn, $ordencompra, $cantidad, $precio, $token)

   $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO ordenes (ordencompra,cantidad,precio,total,token) 
        values (:buyOrder, :cantidad, :precio,:amount, :token)"
        );
   $stmt->execute([
    ':ordencompra'=>$ordencompra,
    ':cantidad'=>$cantidad,
    ':precio'=>$precio,
    ':amount'=>$cantidad*$precio,
    ':token'=>$token
   ]);
 }
```

Además, a tu tabla debieras ponerle un campo `status` y marcas de tiempo `created_at` y `updated_at`.

## Paso 2: Verificar la Transaccion

En el camino feliz el cliente completa el procedimiento y Transbank lo devuelve a la URL donde esperas esa respuesta. Ese request que transbank hace hacia tu sitio contiene un parámetro `token_ws`.

En la versión SOAP era en el body de una petición POST. En la versión REST lo cambiaron o cambiarán para que vaya en el query string de una petición GET.

Sea como sea, **si tienes el $token** puedes ejecutar el último paso que es acusar recibo de la operación. Si no lo haces en 30 segundos, eventualmente Transbank hará una reversa. El paso 2 necesita únicamente el token, y no se puede hacer sin el token.

#### Si usas el API Rest

En Rest puedes usar  **una única vez** el método `commit`

```
 // Rest
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus\Transaction;

$response = Transaction::commit($token);
```

Esa respuesta tiene la forma de una instancia ([TransactionCommitResponse](https://github.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Webpay/WebpayPlus/TransactionCommitResponse.php))  de la cual puedes obtener muchos datos (algunos ya los tienes, otros son irrelevantes, otros sí importan mucho), de entre los cuales el status te dice si pasó o no pasó la transacción.

[De la documentación REST](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay#confirmar-una-transaccion-webpay-plus):

| campo | significado |
| --- | --- |
| status | Estado de la transacción (INITIALIZED, AUTHORIZED, REVERSED, FAILED, NULLIFIED, PARTIALLY_NULLIFIED, CAPTURED). Largo máximo: 64 |
| -- | -- |

El método commit ejecuta un request PUT hacia Transbank, pero si ya lo ejecutaste o quieres saber el status antes de commitear, puedes usar

```
   $response = Transaction::getStatus($token);
```

Que ejecuta un request de tipo GET y devuelve una instancia de [TransactionStatusResponse](https://github.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Webpay/WebpayPlus/TransactionStatusResponse.php), la cual es casi 100% idéntica a la respuesta del commit salvo porque los 4 últimos dígitos de la tarjeta se obtienen con el método `getCardNumber` en uno y con `getCardDetails` en el otro.

Dejo el ejemplo de Transbank donde puedes ver los métodos de `$response`

```js
$response->getVci();
$response->getAmount();
$response->getStatus();
$response->getBuyOrder();
$response->getSessionId();
$response->getCardDetail();
$response->getAccountingDate();
$response->getTransactionDate();
$response->getAuthorizationCode();
$response->getPaymentTypeCode();
$response->getResponseCode();
$response->getInstallmentsAmount();
$response->getInstallmentsNumber();
$response->getBalance();
```

#### Si usas el API SOAP

En soap se utiliza el método [getTransactionResult](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay-soap?l=php#confirmar-una-transaccion-webpay-plus-normal)

```
 // Soap
use Transbank\Webpay\Webpay;
use Transbank\Webpay\Configuration;

$config = Configuration::forTestingWebpayPlusNormal();
$transaction = (new Webpay($config))->getNormalTransaction();
$result = $transaction->getTransactionResult($token)
```

Este método obtiene el status de autorización de la transacción (equivalente al *getStatus*) pero por debajo lanza un segundo request donde llama al método `acknowledgeTransaction` que posiblemente tire un error si ya lo comprobaste antes.

Lo importante es el `status` así que no nos distraigamos. El `$result` tiene un cierto `output` y éste a su vez un cierto `responseCode`.

```
$output = $result->detailOutput;
$status = $output->responseCode;
```

El `status=0` indica éxito. Todos los demás son errores con distintos grados de misterio

| Código | Significado |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Transacción aprobada |
| -1 | Rechazo de transacción - Reintente (Posible error en el ingreso de datos de la transacción) |
| -2 | Rechazo de transacción (Se produjo fallo al procesar la transacción. Este mensaje de rechazo está relacionado a parámetros de la tarjeta y/o su cuenta asociada) |
| -3 | Error en transacción (Interno Transbank) |
| -4 | Rechazo emisor (Rechazada por parte del emisor) |
| -5 | Rechazo - Posible Fraude (Transacción con riesgo de posible fraude) |

Dejo el ejemplo que pone Transbank porque salen las propiedades de $result y de $output

```js
if ($output->responseCode == 0) {
    // Transaccion exitosa, puedes procesar el resultado
    // con el contenido de las variables $result y $output.
    $result->buyOrder;
    $result->sessionId;
    $result->cardDetail->cardNumber;
    $result->cardDetail->cardExpirationDate;
    $result->accountingDate;
    $result->transactionDate;
    $result->vci;
    $result->urlRedirection;
    $output->authorizationCode;
    $output->paymentType;
    $output->amount;
    $output->sharesNumber;
    $output->commerceCode;
    $output->buyOrder;
}
```

#### Actualizar el registro en BBDD

Con ese status puedes actualizar el registro, que habrás identificado usando el token. En la práctica, con solo saber un token ya puedes entrar a todo el flujo "Paso 2"

## Paso 3 Manejo de transacciones interrumpidas

En REST el flujo, si no se ha completado [en 5 minutos](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/documentacion/webpay-plus#crear-una-transaccion), se considera fallido. La documentación del API SOAP [habla de 10 minutos](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay-soap#otros-flujos), pero le creo más a la documentación REST que está más actualizada

Eso significa:

- **Para el cliente**: que si inició un pago en tu sitio, y al llegar a la pasarela Webpay se fue a hacer un sandwich, si demora más de ese lapso tendrá que empezar de nuevo. Se le redirige a tu URL final en donde tu backend verá que la transacción falló.
- **Para la tienda**: que si un proceso de pago figura como pendiente en Transbank y pasó ese lapso, no necesitas seguirlo actualizando una y otra vez. Ya puedes darlo como fallido.

Sabiendo eso tú puedes agendar un cron que cada 5 minutos se traiga todos los registros que se crearon hace más de 5 minutos y siguen sin status.

Dejo una estructura posible para la tabla, en donde la llave primaria es la orden de compra. Es vez de definirla como autoincremental estoy usando:

```
create table ordenes
(ordencompra      bigint(21) unsigned 
    default uuid_short()        
    not null
    primary key
 -- etc etc
 )
```

y más adelante explicaré por qué valdría la pena el esfuerzo extra

```js
create table ordenes
(
ordencompra      bigint(21) unsigned 
    default uuid_short()        
    not null
    primary key,
precio           float               null,
cantidad         int                 null,
total            int                 null,
token            varchar(64)         null,
status           int                 null,
created_at       datetime            default current_timestamp() 
                 not null,
updated_at       datetime            default current_timestamp() 
                 not null on update current_timestamp(),

constraint token unique (token)
);
```

Entonces los casos que quedaron "abandonados" son aquellos cuyo `created_at` tenga más de 5 minutos **y** cuyo `status` sea null.

```
 SELECT token from ordenes 
   WHERE created_at < date_sub( current_timestamp, interval 300 second )
   AND status is null
```

Por cada uno de ellos podrás llamar a commit o a getTransactionResult y actualizarlos, probablemente como fallidos, porque como dije más arriba, con el token ya sabes todo

---

## 4. Opcionalmente, generar buyOrders únicos

Es buena práctica delegar la generación de IDs únicos en vez de armarlos uno mismo. Sugiero esto teniendo en consideración que si usas el timestamp o un autoincremental, en el ambiente de desarrollo **donde todos tenemos el mismo commerceCode**, tarde o temprano habrá colisiones con los buyOrders de otros desarrolladores. En producción, donde tienes un commerceCode único, igual ppodrías estar facilitando que un usuario malicioso enumerase tus transacciones.

En la actualizad la manera elegante de generar un identificador realmente único es usar UUIDs. Lo malo es que Transbank sólo acepta 26 caracteres en el buyOrder (y los uuid necesitan 36). Como sustituto se podría usar por ejemplo [UUID_SHORT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short).

```
    // en vez de $ordencompra = time();
    $ordencompra=$conn->query('SELECT uuid_short()')->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Sin ánimo de recomendar los UUID_SHORT por sobre otro enfoque, me limito a contextualizar que éstos son un pariente más simple de los verdaderos UUIDs. Combinando un id de servidor, más su timestamp de inicio, más un autoincremental global, obtienes un número de 17 cifras que es único en todas las bases de datos de todos los servidores de un mismo cluster.

En teoría se te puede repetir un UUID_SHORT [si se cumplen 3 condiciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818671/is-mysql-uuid-short-comparable-to-uuid#):

- tienes más de 255 servidores (el id del servidor 256 sería 1)
- los servidores que comparten ID inician con menos de 1 segundo de diferencia
- generas más de 16M de UUID_SHORT por segundo

Su suponemos que todos los desarrolladores que usamos Transbank implementamos este enfoque, y todos tenemos un solo servidor con id=1, crucemos los dedos para que no hayamos iniciado mysql al mismo tiempo o bien repartámonos los 16 millones.

### EDIT: Actualizar la fecha de transacción

De seguro hay muchos datos de la transacción que quieres persistir, y no viene al caso detenerme en cada uno. (`authorizationCode` es muy  importante conservarlo si más adelante quieres anular total o parcialmente la transacción), pero es posible que a más de alguien le cause confusión la fecha de transacción que devuelven estos métodos dado que el formato requiere cierta transformación para meterlo en mysql.

Primero, si añades esa fecha con:

```
alter table ordenes
    add transaction_date datetime default null null after token;
```

#### Si usas REST

En rest obtienes la fecha de transacción via

```
    $txDate = $result->getTransactionDate();
```

(y da lo mismo si ese `$result` viene del método `commit` o de `getStatus`, esas dos clases son casi idénticas). Me comentaste que la fecha obtenida por este método era algo como:

```
         2021-01-11T02:47:27.237-03:00
```

#### Si usas SOAP

En el API Soap  la salida de `getTransactionResult` tiene una propiedad equivalente:

```
    $txDate = $result->transactionDate;
```

Según la documentación SOAP la fecha viene en un formato medio exótico

| campo | descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| accountingDate | Fecha de la autorización. Largo: 4, formato MMDD |
| transactionDate | Fecha y hora de la autorización. Largo: 6, formato: MMDDHHmm |

Supongo que cambiaron de opínión, porque hoy responden con  formato [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
         2021-01-31T07:44:39.579Z,
```

La fecha ISO siempre se refiere a UTC. Esa Z se toma como si dijera `2021-01-31T07:44:39.579+00:00`

#### Finalmente

Tanto si viene con el time offset explícito o se infiere del formato ISO,  son strings parseables para PHP.

```
$dateTimeInstance = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
     'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT',
     '2021-01-11T02:47:27.237-03:00'
  );
```

o bien

```
$dateTimeInstance = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
     'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z',
     '2021-01-31T07:44:39.579Z'
  );
```

Con eso tengo un objeto DateTime que puedo manipular, primero ajustándola a la zona horaria UTC (a menos que de verdad quieras usar fecha local)

```
    $dateTimeInstance
        ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Y luego devolviéndola a string con el formato que le gusta a MySQL

```
  $created_at_nice = $dateTimeInstance
                     ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Eso te vevuelve la fecha formateada para mysql.

```
  echo \DateTime::createFromFormat(
     'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT',
     '2021-01-11T02:47:27.237-03:00'
  )->setTimezone(
       new DateTimeZone('UTC')
  )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 // imprime:  2021-01-11 05:47:27
```

## Y qué es Transbank??

Para los lectores de países donde no opera [Transbank](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbank):

Transbank es la única empresa en Chile autorizada a procesar tarjetas de crédito. Esto desde 1989 cuando la sociedad compró la representación de VISA y Mastercard [a un conocido empresario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bancard). Su exclusividad y estructura de propiedad casi 100% bancaria [de vez en cuando genera controversias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbank#Controversias)

El API, que se estancó por unos años, se ha ido modernizando vertiginosamente desde el 2019, pasando de SOAP a REST, añadiendo nuevas modalidades de pago y publicando SDKs para más y más lenguajes, amén de plugins para WooCommerce, Magento y casi todos los SaaS ecommerce. Todo eso está más o menos bien documentado en [TransbankDevelopers.cl](https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/#)

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias por su respuesta, me es de gran ayuda. En un momento , que es lo que tengo implementado hasta el momento, es usar  $ordencompra=time();  // esto no lo uses en producción!, pero como mencionas tu $ordencompra=$conn->query('SELECT uuid_short()')->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); ese numero generado seria unico cierto ?, segun entiendo toma el numero del servidor y lo mezcla con un instante de tiempo dado cuando se hizo la solicitud en la consulta

Comment: Una pregunta mas o duda que tengo mejor dicho, una vez procesada la transaccion, me devuelve el campo transactionDate de la siguente forma 2021-01-31T02:47:27.237-03:00, como puedo almacenar ese campo en la base datos en una columna tipo datetime?

Comment: añadí respuesta a tus preguntas

Comment: estimado, necesito hacerle una consulta, ya que estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente con transbank, al realizar la integracion

Comment: Yo creo que mejor pon otra pregunta para no estirar tanto la actual

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438419/reenvio-del-formulario-borra-mis-variables-de-sesion?noredirect=1#comment782470_438419 ahí le dejo el link con el problema que tengo actualmente, estaría muy agradecido si me puede orientar