# Reenvio del formulario borra mis variables de sesion

Tags: php, cookies, sesiones, transbank

Estimados estoy teniendo el siguiente dolor de cabeza. Tengo una aplicacion donde se pueden realizar compras a traves de internet. Con un sistema de pagos llamado Transbank el cual posee su propio SDK. Dicho sistema solicita datos como orden de compra, sesisionid,precio, entre otros datos, para generar un token y una url que envia al portal de pagos. Luego de realizarse el pago y aprobarse la transaccion el usuario es redirigido mediante post a una vista del portal de pagos, donde se muestran los detalles de la venta, luego de 10 segundos si no se presiona el boton se redirecciona automaticamente a la url final que yo designo en mi script.

El punto es que luego de ser redirigido a dicha url, mis variables de session por alguna razon que desconozco se borran. O si presiono el boton de redirigir antes de los 10 segundos llego a la url final de igual forma, pero le doy a actulziar la pagina , me sale el mensaje de reenvio de formulario y le doy a aceptar y se borran las variables.

Hago login a mi pagina de forma normal. Luego en cada pagina hay un archivo que verify.php que valida si la sesion existe. Lo curioso es que si en dicho archivo lo dejo vacio o de lleno quito la linea session_start(); el problema de las variables desaparece.

Estaria muy agradecido de su orientacion y de su ayuda. Un saludo a todos.

adjunto mis codigos

login.php

```
<?php 
session_set_save_handler(new \SessionHandler());
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';
$con = new Conexion();

$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])) {
        $error = "Por favor ingrese un usuario y contraseña validos";
    }else{
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];   
        $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("correo,clave,nombre,apellido,sid,idusuario","usuarios","correo = ?",array($usuario));
        if (count($datos) > 0){
            $fila = $datos[0];
            $clave = $fila['clave'];
            if(password_verify($_POST['clave'],$clave)){
                date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
                $_SESSION['fecha'] = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
                $_SESSION['correo'] = $fila['correo'];
                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $fila['nombre'];
                $_SESSION['apellido'] = $fila['apellido'];
                $_SESSION['idusuario'] = $fila['idusuario'];
                $_SESSION['sesion-start'] = time();
                $_SESSION['sesion-expire'] = $_SESSION['sesion-start'] + (15 * 60);     
                $sessionID = $fila['sid'];                          
                $actualizar = $con->actualizar("sesion_expira = ?,sid = ?","usuarios","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > sesion_expira",array(NULL,NULL));
                (new \SessionHandler())->destroy($sessionID);
                $_SESSION['sid'] = session_id();                
                $sid = $con->actualizar("sesion_inicia = ?,sesion_expira = ?,sid = ?","usuarios","correo = ?",array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SESSION['sesion-start']), date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SESSION['sesion-expire']), $_SESSION['sid'], $_SESSION['correo']));
                header("location: ../profile"); 
                exit();
            }else{
                $error = 'La contraseña ingresada no es valida';
            }
        }else{
            $error = "El usuario ingresado no existe";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

verify.php

```
<?php
session_start();

setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
include "conexion.php";
$con = new Conexion();
if(!isset($_SESSION['correo'])){
    $con->desconectar();
    header('Location: '.$raiz.'login');
}else{
    $ahora = time();
    if($ahora > $_SESSION['sesion-expire']){
        $liberar = $con->actualizar("sid = ?","usuarios","correo = ?",array(NULL,$_SESSION['correo']));
        unset($_SESSION['fecha']);
        unset($_SESSION['nombre']);
        unset($_SESSION['apellido']);       
        unset($_SESSION['sesion-start']);
        unset($_SESSION['sesion-expire']);
        $con->desconectar();
        session_regenerate_id();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.$raiz.'login');
    }else{
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
        $_SESSION['sesion-expire'] = time() + (15 * 60);
        $actualizar = $con->actualizar("sesion_expira = ?","usuarios","correo = ?",array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SESSION['sesion-expire']), $_SESSION['correo']));     
        $inactivos = $con->actualizar("sesion_expira = ?,sid= ?","usuarios","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > sesion_expira",array(NULL,NULL));
    }
} 

?>
```

procesarventa.php donde se genera el token y la url

```
<?php session_start();include '../logica/conexion.php'; require_once '../vendor/autoload.php'; use Transbank\Webpay\Webpay; use Transbank\Webpay\Configuration; use Transbank\Webpay\WebPayNormal;
class ProcesarVenta {

    public function Venta(){
        
        $HTML = '';
        $con = new Conexion();      
        $cantidad = filter_var($_POST['cantidad'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("*","escala_creditos","cantidad = ?",array($cantidad));
        $precio = $datos[0]['total'];
        $orden = $con->obtenerdatos2($con->conexion->prepare("SELECT uuid_short() AS orden"));
        $numeroorden = $orden[0]['orden'];
        $sessionid = $_SESSION['sid'];
        $returnUrl = "http://localhost/ecuservi/profile/retornarventa.php";
        $finalUrl = "http://localhost/ecuservi/profile/ventafinal.php";
        $urlRepository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-webpay-credenciales/master/";
        $dirFiles = "integracion/Webpay%20Plus%20-%20CLP/597020000540";
        $contentPublicCert = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".crt");
        $contentPrivateKey = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".key");
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $configuration->setCommerceCode(597020000540);
        $configuration->setEnvironment("INTEGRACION");
        $configuration->setPrivateKey($contentPrivateKey);
        $configuration->setPublicCert($contentPublicCert);
        $webpay = new Webpay($configuration);
        $transaction = $webpay->getNormalTransaction();
        $response = $transaction->initTransaction($precio,$numeroorden,$sessionid,$returnUrl,$finalUrl);
        $HTML .= '  <p>ORDEN DE COMPRA: '.$numeroorden.'</p>
                    <p>TOTAL A PAGAR: $'.number_format($precio, 0, ",", ".").'</p>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <form action="'.$response->url.'" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="token_ws" value="'.$response->token.'">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pagar</button>
                    </form>';
        return $HTML;
        
    }   

    
    
}
$procesar = new ProcesarVenta();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    $html1 = $procesar->Venta(); 
    $data = array(
        "html1" => $html1
    );
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>
```

retornaventa.php donde se realizan las acciones de registro en la base de datos

```
<?php 

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';include '../logica/conexion.php';
$con = new Conexion; 

use Transbank\Webpay\Webpay;
use Transbank\Webpay\Configuration;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebPayNormal;

$urlRepository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-webpay-credenciales/master/";
$dirFiles = "integracion/Webpay%20Plus%20-%20CLP/597020000540";
$contentPublicCert = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".crt");
$contentPrivateKey = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".key");
$configuration = new Configuration();
$configuration->setCommerceCode(597020000540);
$configuration->setEnvironment("INTEGRACION");
$configuration->setPrivateKey($contentPrivateKey);
$configuration->setPublicCert($contentPublicCert);
$webpay = new Webpay($configuration);
$transaction = $webpay->getNormalTransaction();

$tokenWs = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'token_ws');
$result = $transaction->getTransactionResult($tokenWs);
$output = $result->detailOutput;
$comercio = 'WebPay';
$total = $output->amount;
$query_cantidad = $con->obtenerdatos("cantidad","escala_creditos","total = ?",array($total));
$cantidad = $query_cantidad[0]['cantidad'];
$fechaautorizacion = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT',$result->transactionDate);
$fechaautorizacion->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Santiago'));
$fecha = $fechaautorizacion->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ordencompra = $output->buyOrder;
$codigoautorizacion = $output->authorizationCode;
$numerotarjeta = str_pad($result->cardDetail->cardNumber, 16, "X", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$idusuario = 'USER10001';
if($output->sharesNumber == 0){
    $numerocuotas = 0;
    $montocuotas = 0;
}else{
    $numerocuotas = $output->sharesNumber;
    $montocuotas = $output->sharesAmount;
}
if($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VD'){
    $tipoventa = 'Débito';  
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VN'){
    $tipoventa = 'Normal';  
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VC'){
    $tipoventa = 'En Cuotas';   
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'SI' or $output->paymentTypeCode == 'S2' or $output->paymentTypeCode == 'NC'){
    $tipoventa = 'Cuotas S/I';  
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VP'){
    $tipoventa = 'Prepago'; 
}else{
    $tipoventa = '';    
}
if ($output->responseCode == 0) {
    
    echo '  <script>
                window.localStorage.clear();
                window.localStorage.setItem("result",JSON.stringify('.json_encode($result).'));
            </script>';
    

    
    $query = $con->insertar("?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?","creditos",array($ordencompra,$codigoautorizacion,$numerotarjeta,$numerocuotas,$montocuotas,$tipoventa,$total,$cantidad,$fecha,"Aprobada","123",$comercio,$idusuario));

    $query_creditos = $con->actualizar("creditos = creditos + ?","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($cantidad,$idusuario));
}
?>
<?php if($output->responseCode == 0){?>
<form action="<?php echo $result->urlRedirection?>" method="post" id="return-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="token_ws" value="<?php echo $tokenWs;?>">
</form>


<script>
    document.getElementById('return-form').submit();
</script>
<?php }?>
```

ventafinal.php donde se redirecciona finlmente al ususario

```
<?php $raiz = "../"; include $raiz.'logica/verify.php';include $raiz.'header2.php'; $titulo = "Portal - Comprar Creditos"; $titulo2 = "PORTAL CRÉDITOS";?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table tablas table-borderless table-sm tabla_5 m-0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Orden de Compra</td><td id="precio"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Código de Autorización</td><td id="codigoautorizacion"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Orden de Compra</td><td id="precio"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Orden de Compra</td><td id="precio"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
        <p>Tarjeta  <span id="numerotarjeta"></span></p>
        <p>N° Orden  <span id="ordencompra"></span></p>
        <p>Tipo Pago  <span id="tipopago"></span></p>   
        <p>Fecha Transacción  <span id="fechatransaccion"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
        let result = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("result"));
        document.getElementById('precio').innerText = result.detailOutput.amount;
        document.getElementById('codigoautorizacion').innerText = result.detailOutput.authorizationCode;
        document.getElementById('numerotarjeta').innerText = result.cardDetail.cardNumber;
        document.getElementById('ordencompra').innerText = result.detailOutput.buyOrder;
        document.getElementById('tipopago').innerText = result.detailOutput.paymentTypeCode;
        document.getElementById('fechatransaccion').innerText = result.transactionDate;
    });
</script>   
<?php include $raiz.'footer2.php';?>
```

Comment: Bueno en primer lugar ```session_start()``` va al inicio de todo nada debe ir antes de ```session_start()```  en localhost aveces se omite el error pero cuando pasa a producción genera el error y segundo debes verificar que solo haya un ```session_start()``` por archivo osea si llamas a ```verify.php``` ya no debes de poner otra vez ```session_start()```  dicho esto verifica se haces algo de eso y si no dímelo y revisaré detenidamente el código

Comment: El session_start() solo está en el archivo verify.php y en el login.php, en los demás archivos está en aquellos en donde requiero hacer uso de alguna variable solamente

Comment: en la pantalla adonde llegas al final de todo apareces deslogueado. ¿Se puede resumir el problema general en esa descripción? Me mareé (marié?) con tanta información y tanto código.

Comment: en resumidas cuentas ese es el problema, en la pagina final que devuelve tranbank despues de aprobarse la venta llego deslogueado, se pierden todas las variables de sesion que se generan al hacer login. El session_star esta en todas las paginas donde uso las variables.

Comment: puedes hacer la prueba de -al llegar a esa pantalla final- en vez de recargar con F5 poner otra url de tu sitio en el navegador y ver si estás logueado en esa donde llegues? El F5 genera otro POST, necesito que hagas eso por GET, por eso hay que poner la url a mano en este ejercicio

Comment: si ingreso a otro url aparezco logeado, pero si vuelvo a realizar el proceso de hacer una compra me aparece el error que se perdio la variablke de session que estoy usando $_SESSION['isusuario']

Comment: Cual podría ser el error que me esta dejando deslogueado en el sistema?

Answer (score 1):

La sesión de php tiene como llave una cookie que el visitante recibe en su navegador. A la siguiente visita el backend revisa la cookie cuando pones `session_start()`. Si la cookie que busca existe y se corresponde con una sesión existente, entonces se hidrata su contenido y con ello se puebla la sesión. Luego el flujo sigue.

En algún momento del segundo semestre de 2020, tanto en [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/features) como en [Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/08/changes-to-samesite-cookie-behavior/#:%7E:text=We%20are%20changing%20the%20default,are%20slowly%20introducing%20this%20change.) se cambió el setting `SameSite` de las cookies de `None` a `Lax`. El resultado que esto tiene es que, para peticiones de tipo `POST` a otro sitio,
éste la recibe **sin cookies**. En realidad la cookie sigue ahí, pero esa petición en particular es, en buenas cuentas anónima. Por eso la siguiente carga de página, si es por GET, te considera logueado.

Yo veo tres caminos para resolverlo.

1. Antes de llamar a `session_start` , configura la cookie de sesión con `SameSite: None`. Para que esto tenga efecto debe además ser segura (o estar en localhost, me parece?)

O sea, sin https esto no funciona

```
  session_set_cookie_params(['SameSite'=>'None','Secure'=>true]);
```

2. Provocar tú mismo la redirección mediante GET... por javascript. No estoy seguro si un header de redirección enviado por PHP sirva en este caso.

ej

```
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time; URL=new_url" />
```

o bien

```
    <script>
      window.location.href = "/ventafinal.php";
    </script>
```

Esto tiene el defecto de que se pierden los datos recibidos por POST a menos que los guardes en otro lado... que no puede ser la sesión porque no la tienes.

3. Puedes recuperar el id de la sesión "perdida" en base al buyOrder o al token. Tal como sugerí en la respuesta a [Como crear ordenes de compra con PHP y MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424512/como-crear-ordenes-de-compra-con-php-y-mysql/424624?noredirect=1#comment784282_424624), en donde dice: **Pero esa tabla no estaría completa sin el campo token**

Cuando inicias la transacción tienes

```
 $response = $transaction->initTransaction( 
    $precio,
    $numeroorden,
    $sessionid,
    $returnUrl,
    $finalUrl
 );
```

Si al momento de iniciar la transacción guardas del lado del servidor (caché, BBDD)  una tupla **[$numeroorden,$sessionid]**

```
 $con->insertar('? ? ','transacciones_pendientes',[$numeroorden,$sessionid]);
```

Cuando el request POST te llega de vuelta obtienes el buyOrder para conocer el ID de la sesión perdida.

```
$tokenWs = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'token_ws');
$result = $transaction->getTransactionResult($tokenWs);
$output = $result->detailOutput;
$ordencompra = $output->buyOrder;


$session_id = $con->obtenerdatos(
   "sessionid","transacciones_pendientes","numeroorden = ?",[$ordencompra])
);
```

Y teniendo ese valor, puedes hacer

```
session_id($session_id);
```

Y la habrás rehidratado.

Comment: tengo una pequeña duda, en el segundo archivo donde se procesa la transaccion de transbank luego de aceptar el pago, actualemte de esta forma envio a la pantalla final   <form action="<?php echo $result->urlRedirection?>" method="post" id="return-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="token_ws" value="<?php echo $tokenWs;?>">/form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('return-form').submit();
</script>, pero me mencionas que lo haga asi  <script>window.location.href = "/ventafinal.php"; </script>, pero de ese modo no pasa por la pantalla de transbank que muestra el detalle de la venta

Comment: No. Lo que estoy diciendo es que donde transbank te deja al final de todo, habría que recuperar la sesión con alguno de esos trucos. No toques nada de los pasos anteriores mejor

Comment: Eh seguido lo que usted me menciona, en la pagina ventafinal.php pongo lo siguiente include '../logica/conexion.php';
$con = new Conexion; 
$tokenWs = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'token_ws');
$query_id = $con->obtenerdatos("*","transacciones_pendientes","token = ?",array($tokenWs));
$sessionId = $query_id[0]['sid'];
session_id($sessionId);
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION), al cabo de 3-5 minutos recargo la pagina con F5 y sigo logueado, me voy a otra URL y efectivamente sigo logueado, pero si vuelvo a ejecutar el proceso de venta, se pierde nuevamamente la sesion