# ¿Porque la API de Tranksbank me cierra la sesión en una aplicación Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, transbank

Tengo una aplicación web en Laravel, la hemos integrado correctamente para realizar pagos. Ahora surge la problemática de anular pagos. El problema es que al momento de anular, al volver a la URL de redirección que solicita la API, tengo que consultar en la base de datos pero me arroja un error porque, en la práctica me cierra la sesión actual, entonces, al hacer el llamado por medio de eloquent arroja un error, ya que el usuario deja de estar logueado.

¿Alguien tiene experiencia con esto?

El flujo es crear una transacción -> ir al portal de transkbank ->  anular la transacción -> retornar una vista al usuario con el mensaje de que la transacción ha sido anulada.

El problema surge antes de retornar la vista, al hacer una consulta con eloquent.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado la imagen con el error, aunque no tiene relación. Ya que el error es que no encuentra el objeto id porque como cierra sesión no ejecuta la consulta correctamente.

Comment: Si recargas esa pantalla verás que sí estás logueado. Lo que pasa es que desde octubre 2020, una petición POST desde otro dominio no envía cookies, pero las cookies (la de sesión es la que importa) sí están en el navegador. Mira esta respuesta a ver si es tu caso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438419/reenvio-del-formulario-borra-mis-variables-de-sesion?noredirect=1#answer-440122

Comment: Puede ser por la verificación del token CSRF que genera laravel. Intenta agregando una excepcion a la ruta donde muestras el mensaje de que la transacción ha sido anulada.